# clang/gcc cannot set global variables to an address constant minus another address constant

Tags: c, gcc, clang, elf, c17

The program below compiles without errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char addr_a[8];
char addr_b[8];

unsigned long my_addr = (unsigned long)addr_b - 8;                          // PASS
// unsigned long my_addr = (unsigned long)addr_b - (unsigned long)addr_a;   // FAIL (error: initializer element is not constant)

int main() {
        printf("%lx\n", my_addr);
        return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, when I set `unsigned long my_addr = (unsigned long)addr_b - (unsigned long)addr_a` the compiler throws "error: initializer element is not constant."

I know globals can only be initialized with a constant expression. I also know that the types of constant expressions that can be used in an initializer for a global are specified in section 6.6p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

Note that an address constant minus an integer constant is allowed, but not an address constant minus another address constant.

**Question:**

Why does the C standard restrict the ways you can initialize global variables? What is stopping the C standard from accepting `unsigned long my_addr = (unsigned long)addr_b - (unsigned long)addr_a`?

**Why would you want this?**

Suppose `addr_a` and `addr_b` represent the start and end of the `.text` section respectively. A program may want to map the `.text` section, which has size `(unsigned long)addr_b - (unsigned long)addr_a`. The [trusted-firmware-a](https://git.trustedfirmware.org/TF-A/trusted-firmware-a.git) project does this in Boot Loader stage 2 (BL2). See [`BL_CODE_END - BL_CODE_BASE`](https://git.trustedfirmware.org/TF-A/trusted-firmware-a.git/tree/include/plat/arm/common/arm_def.h?h=v2.6#n326), which is used in [arm_bl2_setup.c](https://git.trustedfirmware.org/TF-A/trusted-firmware-a.git/tree/plat/arm/common/arm_bl2_setup.c?h=v2.6#n194).

Answer (score 4):

Objects with *static storage duration* (i.e. globals, plus locals defined as `static`) can only be initialized with a **constant expression**.

The types of constant expression that can be used in an initializer for such an object is specified in section 6.6p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> More  latitude  is  permitted  for  constant  expressions  in
> initializers. Such  a  constant expression shall be, or evaluate to,
> one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address  constant  for  a  complete  object  type  plus  or  minus  an  integer  constant expression.

Note that an address constant plus an integer constant is allowed, but not an address constant plus another address constant.

Granted this still isn't *exactly* what you have, as you have address constants casted to integer type.  So let's check 6.6p6 which defines an **integer constant expression**:

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and
> shall  only  have  operands that are integer constants, enumeration
> constants, character constants, sizeof expressions  whose  results
> are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and  floating
> constants that are the immediate operands of casts. **Cast operators in
> an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert  arithmetic
> types  to  integer  types**,  except  as  part  of  an operand to the
> `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

This paragraph doesn't allow for casting an address constant to an integer type as part of an integer constant expression, but apparently this seems to be supported as an extension.

Comment: *This paragraph doesn't allow for casting an address constant to an integer type*  Does [6.3.2.3p6 (C11)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6) apply? "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle That applies in the general case, but I think this case adds restrictions.

Comment: I'm curious why the C standard restricts the ways you can initialize objects with static storage duration. Could it be because of limitations of the ELF format? Maybe relocation entries cannot hold information representing an address constant plus another address constant?

Comment: @Jorge: Yes, that's essentially correct.  For example, for x86-64, see the [psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf), table 4.9, and note the absence of any `S+S` option.  Technically, I guess C had the restriction first (the language long predates ELF), but probably in early days, both the language and the existing tools were limited to those relocations with the clearest real-world use, and so far neither the language nor the tools has much incentive to support something not supported by the other.

Comment: @jorge: the C standard is not based on ELF. But I would guess that few linkers can handle a relocation entry representing the sum of two addresses; there's no obvious use for such a thing. So it wouldn't be surprising if the C committee wasn't prepared to force implementations to create a linker which could do that.

Answer (score 0):

> What is stopping the C standard from accepting unsigned long my_addr = (unsigned long)addr_a + (unsigned long)addr_b?

The underlying reason is "Because why would anyone want that?"  It's not meaningful to add two absolute addresses together; the result isn't the address of anything in particular.

It's thus a sort of chicken-and-egg thing.  The language doesn't support it because it's useless, but also because existing linkers and object file formats don't support such a relocation.  For instance, for ELF on x86-64, see the [psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) Table 4.9 for a list of supported relocations, and note there is no `S+S`.  And the linkers don't support it because it's useless, and because the language doesn't require it to be supported.

I guess originally, the tools probably came before the language (the earliest C compilers would have used linkers designed for assembly programs).  So the original tools probably didn't support this, the language saw no need to demand that they do so, and over time, neither one ever saw a need to add it.